# Can I send excel file and raw json in request body in single request to api?

Tags: node.js, json, file, raw

Can I send excel file and raw json in request body in single request to api from postman?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FormData`

```
const exampleData = {
 name: 'test'
};
const bodyFormData= new FormData();
bodyFormData.append('file', <FILE>)
bodyFormData.append('jsonData', JSON.stringify(exampleData))

axios({
  method: "post",
  URL: <URL>,
  data: bodyFormData,
  headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
})
```

- Get this request in a server
- use some middleware
- in the middleware you can split the `file` and `jsonData` for the following steps

Comment: But I dont see any such option on postman where I can send both together

Comment: You can use this one example: [https://prnt.sc/BORD2ePFsLQS](https://prnt.sc/BORD2ePFsLQS)